# Quicksort recursion error

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

while implementing quicksort i am getting a problem:
    enter code here

```
def partition(list,p,r):
  i=p-1
  j=p
  x=list[r]
  for j in range(p,r)://the program is working fine but if i replace it with only r its not working anymore,why is that p is always 0and the loop will run similarly
    if list[j]<list[r]:
        i=i+1
        temp=list[i]
        list[i]=list[j]
        list[j]=temp
 temp1=list[i+1]
 list[i+1]=x
 list[r]=temp1
 return i+1

def quicksort(list,p,r):
    if p<r:
     q=partition(list,p,r)
     quicksort(list,p,q-1)
     quicksort(list,q+1,r)
    return list
```

list= quicksort([5,3,1,6,7,9,8],0,6)
  print list

it is sorting but if i change the loop range its showing error